# Can't figure out selenium - unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to learn how to click around using selenium. I have tried some different websites like reddit, google etc without success.

```
driver.get('https://www.dropbox.com/login')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="' + 'https://www.dropbox.com/forgot?email_from_login=' + '"]').click()
```

and

```
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Sign in')
```

They both exist but neither works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use any of the ways such as :

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Forgot your password')]").click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're being a little specific in your xpath, so there're many more ways you might bugger something up. Using the xpath you can simply do:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='forgot-password-link']").click()
```

I make no assumptions, but just in case you aren't already, there's a very handy tool in Chrome's inspect element which lets you click an element and jumps to its node in the inspector.

Comment: Yes, I am trying with the inspector. I got the same error using your code unfortunately, 'Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"forgot-password-link//*[@class='']"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)'

Comment: Sorry - the one you used was before my edit. Try with this one please, I put the text in the wrong part of the quotes!

Comment: Yes, that works. I'll try to see if I can figure out selenium by that

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've been building a Selenium Instagram bot and as you can imagine there are tons of buttons to click. The class and css selectors kept giving me errors, but learning how to use xpaths like this made it so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-button.signin-button.button-primary")).click()
```

Comment: Well, at least it was found. It didn't work though, 'Compound class names not permitted'

Comment: Why should the OP (or anyone else) just "try" this? It makes you sound like you are not sure the solution will work. Besides, you are answering not only to the OP, but also to future readers, so please elaborate a bit on why this should work; either in text around the code, or comments within the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shorter single class selector to Sign In button

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".login-button").click()
```

Sign in with Google

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sign-in-text").click()
```

For forgot password

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".forgot-password-link").click()
```

Single class css selectors will be the fastest method (faster than xpath and compound class)